# Tokenservice Capability Not Found Error While registering discovery service

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion, discovery-service

I have installed Content Delivery services as a windows service on the Microsoft Azure server now I am trying to register these capabilities into the discovery service but I am getting error showing TokenServiceCapability not found issue, hence none of the services are getting registered. I have checked the config file but the couldn't found any such issue. I have checked all the services are up and running, the token service  http://localhost:8082/token.svc is also working. I am not able to figure out what could be the reason behind this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The above issue has been resolved after I update the rules set to false in the cd_ambient_conf config file.                                                                      <!-- Rules definition for read/write shielding of services. -->
        <Rules Enabled="false"/>

Answer (score 1):

The actual error in the above issue is `"Path not allowed"` and not the INFO message which says `"TokenServiceCapability not found"`.

It looks like you had discovery service with `"OAuthEnabled=false"` and `Rules` enabled as true which can cause this issue.

In general, if you have OAuth disabled, then rules must be disabled.

Also if you have OAuth disabled, you can remove `ClientId`, `ClientSecret` and `TokenServiceUrl` from the `<ConfigurationRepository...>` section of the config used by registration tool.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue has been resolved to updating the rules set to false in the 
cd_ambient_conf config

```
<!-- Rules definition for read/write shielding of services. --> 
<Rules Enabled="false"/>
```